# configure caddyfile to work with multiwebsite on odoo-14

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, caddy

I am using multi website on my odoo instance and just made the switch from nginx to caddy. Im trying to configure caddy to work with all my domains, but i always end up on the same odoo website

Here is my caddyfile

```
domain1.com {
    redir https://www.domain1.com{uri} 
}
domain2.com {
    redir https://www.domain2.com{uri} 
}
domain3.com {
    redir https://www.domain3.com{uri} 
}

www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com, www.domain3.com {
    reverse_proxy http://127.0.0.1:8069 { 
        header_up X-Forwarded-Proto https
        header_up X-Forwarded-Host {host}
        header_up X-Url-Scheme {scheme}
        header_up X-Real-IP {remote}
    }

    encode gzip zstd
    file_server
    log
}
```

Normally adding the headers should be enough for odoo to recognize the domains, right?

I have set the domains on odoo website configuration

== EDIT ==
Basically what I need is to translate these nginx "statements" to work with Caddy

```
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Multi website redirections with Caddy

Caddyfile configuration

```bash
www.example.info {
    redir https://example.com{uri}
}

exampleone.com {
    redir https://example.com{uri} 
}
exampletwo.com {
    redir https://example.com{uri} 
}
examplethree.com {
    redir https://example.com{uri} 
}

# Redirecting Here
https://example.com {
    ......
}
```

Refer for [More Caddy Examples](https://github.com/JinnaBalu/docker-caddy/tree/main/caddy-file-examples)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't solve the issue at all. The redirections in my caddy file work totally fine. The problem is, that odoo doesn't recognise which domain the client is coming from and always returns the same website. That is why the problems lies within the headers . Basically what I would need is proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
these exact nginx statements "translated" to use in caddy. How is this possible?

Comment: I edited the question to further clarify this, maybe you can help @Jinaa Balu